# JUNIT запуск тестового класса

Tags: java, junit

При запуске тестового класса перед каждым методом создается новый экземпляр этого класса. Почему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из за этого я не могу проверить тест на ошибку, если не создавать новый экземпляр

```
@Before
public void initialize(){
    logAnalyzer = new LogAnalyzer();// если я коментирую эту строку то второй тест должен быть красный
    logAnalyzer.initialize();
}
```

У меня постоянно создается новый экземпляр LogAnalyzer, потому что при запуске второго метода создается новый экземпляр TestLogAnalyzer. На скринах показал

Comment: Потому что  @Before  выполняется перед каждым методом, а там у вас создание экземпляра класса прописано.

Comment: здравствуй, стековерфло копи паст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Библиотека Junit предполагает, что тесты являются независимыми друг от друга. Создание нового экземпляра класс для каждого метода позволяет гарантировать. Подробнее можно посмотреть здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010222/junit-new-instance-before-invoking-each-test-method-what-are-the-benefits или в книге JUnit in Action, Third Edition. Возможно, вам поможет аннотация @BeforeClass, https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/BeforeClass.html